# Understand Logarithm of Bar values manipulation step.

Tags: calculus, logic, logarithms, education

Currently I am learning Logarithm , but I can't understand the manipulation of the following Highlighted step how it comes

How the result come after after `1/2 (bar 1.7563)`

[image]

Kindly guide me on the same.

Comment: What does the bar over the numbers mean?  I've never seen that notation, except for an infinitely repeating decimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logarithm is broken up into two parts.

The first part is the integral part the the rest is the fractional part **WHICH MUST BE POSITIVE**.

The integral part takes care of the number of decimal places of the original number.

For example, In log(8432) = 3. 9259, 3 means the original number (ie. 8432) has 3 + 1 digits. Then, (bar 2). 7563 means -2 + 0.7563 = -1.2437

But -1.2437 means -1 – 0.2437 which is not an allowable format of a logarithm.

Therefore, we have to re-write as

– 1 – 0.2437 = – 1 – 0.2437 + 1 – 1

= –1 – 1 + 1 – 0.2437

= – 2 + (1 – 0.2437)

= - 2 + 0.7563

= (bar2. 7563)

**Added info**

Let $p = \frac {bar(1).7563}{2}$. After division, $p$ becomes $bar(0.5).37815$, which is NOT in the allowable format because the integral part is NOT integral any more.

The book makes the suggestion:- Convert $p$ to $\frac {bar(2) + 1.7563}{2}$ first.

Then, $p = \frac{ bar (2)}{2} + \frac {1.7563}{2} = bar (1) + 0.8782 = bar (1).8782$

---

There is also another (could-be more understandable) way to get around it:-

Step-1) First, obtain its numerical equivalent (but NOT in the allowable format).

∴ $p = \frac {-1 + 0.7563}{2} = \frac {– 0.2437}{2} = – 0.12185 = – 0.1218$ (approx.)

Step-2) Then, convert the above back to the standard form.

∴ $p = – 0.1218 = (– 1) + (1 + – 0.1218) = (– 1) + (0.8782) = bar (1).8782$.

Comment: Sorry , But can you explain with a simple example.

Comment: If the above is too complicate. Try:- (bar1.7563) = -1 + 0.7563 = -1 -1 + 1 + 0.7563 = -2 + 1.7563 = (bar2) + 1.7563. Going through all these trouble is because we have to do a little preparation for the division by 2 in the later stage.

Comment: Thanks a lot for great explanation. Really helpful.

Comment: @swetavaishnani U r welcome.

Comment: @swetavaishnani I have added another approach.

Answer (score 1):

Bar 1 is not divisible by 2 so you add another bar 1  to the characteristic part to make it divisible by 2
because you added bar 1, add 1 to the mantissa part and then divide the two parts separately and then add the results as shown below

**Characteristic**

bar 1  +bar 1 =bar 2
bar2 *1/2= bar1

**Mantissa**
0.7563+1=1.7563
1.7563*1/2=0.8782

Adding the characteristic and mantissa gives
1 bar+0.8782= 1 bar.8782